# Is there any way to draw graph using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

can we draw graph with zend framework. I so, how to do data thing ? Is there some online resource to get familiar with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Zend Framework, but I seriously recommend [Google Chart Tools API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html). It's easy to use and customize and is pretty powerful!

Edit: When I last used it, I generated the data using plain old PHP by looking at a [javascript example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization) and spotting the pattern, then just having php `echo`'s everywhere I need them.

Answer (score 0):

For creating graphs use http://thejit.org/

Answer (score 0):

It will take some brain power, but I would recommend looking into [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting.html) simply because [Zend has some built view helpers for dojo](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.dojo.html). At the end of the day, your going to have to integrate what ever solution your pick yourself.